# Delete points not within land but with an offset

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have a Android App that uses GPS and reports it to the backend. For some reason (mock location or low gps accuracy I guess) a lot of measurements were saved with coordinates beyond lands.

I'm writing a python pandas/geopandas short code to filter out those but it seems not to be that trivial.

My initial idea was to join registered GPS points with hi-res (10m) land shapes.

```py
#
# df initial dataframe with points

geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.longitude, df.latitude)]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
geodf = gp.GeoDataFrame(df[['longitude','latitude']],geometry = geometry, crs=crs)

world = gp.read_file("../GeoPandas/natural-earth-vector/10m_physical/ne_10m_land.shp")

gpd_joined = gp.sjoin(geodf,world, how='inner', op='intersects', lsuffix='left', rsuffix='right')
```

However there are may false-positives (shape file inaccuracy?) on the coastline. I'd like to keep those samples.
(blue -- land polygon, markers - points marked for deletion)

[image: false-positive sample1]
[image: false-positive sample2]

Generally speaking my idea is to clean-up the set by deleting most obvious e.g in the middle of the ocean keeping a "border buffer" around the coastline.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to create such a border/buffer. Simple expanding polygon with `scale` function scales up polygon starting from its most center point. What I'd love to achieve is to expand it by desired size uniformly.

I've tried then using the "Oceans" shape and down-scale it

```py
gdfOceansSS.geometry.scale(xfact=0.9, yfact=0.9, zfact=1.0, origin=(0,0,0))
```

but without success.

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I've just found-out that simple gp.buffer will do the work:

```py
gdfWorldSS.geometry = world.geometry.buffer(1)
```

[image: buffer]